# Rails 6 query records where includes with conditions and count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `category` and one called `events` where category `has_many` events.

Event has a column `scheduled_at`

I want to get all categories that have events in the future.

This is some pseudo code I am playing with:

```
Category.includes(:events).where("events.scheduled_at > ?", Time.current).count(events) > 0
```

Any ideas how I get this query right?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid error `no such column: events.scheduled_at`, consider adding [references](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-references) at the end of your query, like this

```
Category.includes(:events).where("events.scheduled_at > ?", Time.current).references(:events)
```

Also, instead of `count(events)` just use [size](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-size)

Comment: Thanks. I don't get an error yet because I am still trying to write the query that I can test then.

Answer (score 0):

To get all Categories do following

```rb
@categories = Category.includes(:events).where("events.scheduled_at > ?", Time.current)
```

Above will load all categories matching the condition and to count categories, use the loaded records

```rb
@category_count = @categories.size
```